# why identifier of a wrapper class object does not work as a reference variable

Tags: java, autoboxing

My question involves wrapper classes. I know that when we store a primitive type literal by using wrapper classes, we are storing it as a object of that wrapper class so object's identifier will be a reference variable (somehow like a pointer in c++). For instance, in `Integer wi = new Integer("56")`, `wi` is a reference variable. But if that is true:

1. Why can I do `wi++` or `wi +=2`? Why does compiler deal with those reference variables like normal primitive variables? Doesn't a reference variable store reference of a object?
2. Given `Integer wi = new Integer("56")` and `int pi = 56`, why does `(wi == pi)`  returns true. Isn't wi supposed to store a reference (address)?

And another question: When a reference variable is passed to a method as parameter it counts as passing by reference so the modifiction that happens 
to that reference variable should affect it's value but it doesn't:

```
public class Main {
  void show(Integer x){
    x *=100 ;
  }

  void goo(int x){
    x *=100 ;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main mn = new Main() ;
    Integer wi = new Integer("86");
    int pi = 86 ;

    mn.goo(pi);
    System.out.println(pi); //output = 86

    mn.show(wi);
    System.out.println(wi); //output = 86, shouldn't it be 8600?
  }
}
```

Comment: 1) Autoboxing introudce in java 1.5 2) Cause Integer cache values between -128 to 127, if you do `j=new Integer(5)` and `Integer i =5` i **doubt** that `i==j` returns true 3) You shouldn't use `new Integer` constructor always `valueOf` or `parseXXX`

Comment: It will work fine.Along with several other constructors, it is one of them. Integer o = new Integer("86");

Comment: @nachokk That's correct (returns false) when comparing, by reference, two Integer objects. But when comparing `int i = 56` and `Integer.valueOf(56)`, the 'reference' equality is true, I imagine because the `Integer` is unboxed and two `int` types are compared. @chrylis There is indeed an `Integer` constructor that accepts a `String`.

Comment: @Malwaregeek I had somehow managed to overlook that. Still a Bad Thing, though. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

the statement `mn.goo(pi)` passes the copy of value `86` while `mn.show(wi)` passes the copy of reference variable which holds the same object.

> 1. why can i do this? wi++ or wi +=2 .i mean why does compiler deal with those reference vriables like normal primitve variables?(doesn't a reference variable store reference of a object?)

Because of the concept of `autoboxing` and `auto-unboxing`, `wi` is converted to `primitive`, incremented, then then converted back to `Wrapper`

> 2.or if we have==>" Integer wi = new Integer("56") " and "int pi = 56" . why does (wi == pi) returns true. isn't wi supposed to store refernce (address)

This is because for `Integer` wrapper classes, the `==` will return true for the value till `128`. This is by design

For your doubts regarding passign primitives and object references, Please study these programs

```
class PassPrimitiveToMethod
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        int a = 5;
        System.out.println("Before Passing value to modify() a = " + a);
        PassPrimitiveToMethod p = new PassPrimitiveToMethod();
        p.modify(a);
        System.out.println("After passing value to modify() a = " + a);
        // the output is still the same because the copy of the value is passed to the method and not the copy of the bits like in refrence variables
        // hence unlike the reference variables the value remains unchanged after coming back to the main method

    }   


    void modify(int b)
    {
        b = b + 1;
        System.out.println("Modified number  b = " + b);
        // here the value passed is the copy of variable a
        // and only the copy is modified here not the variable 
    }       

}
```

The output is

```
Before Passing value to modify() a = 5
Modified number  b = 6
After passing value to modify() a = 5
```

Passing object reference to method

```
class PassReferenceToMethod
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Dimension d = new Dimension(5,10);
        PassReferenceToMethod p = new PassReferenceToMethod();
        System.out.println("Before passing the reference d.height = " + d.height);
        p.modify(d);            // pass the d reference variable
        System.out.println("After passing the reference d.height = " + d.height);
        // the value changes because we are passing the refrence only which points to the single and same object
        // hence the values of the object are modified 
    } 

    void modify(Dimension dim)
    {
        dim.height = dim.height + 1;
    }   


}
```

The output is

```
class PassReferenceToMethod
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Dimension d = new Dimension(5,10);
        PassReferenceToMethod p = new PassReferenceToMethod();
        System.out.println("Before passing the reference d.height = " + d.height);
        p.modify(d);            // pass the d reference variable
        System.out.println("After passing the reference d.height = " + d.height);
        // the value changes because we are passing the refrence only which points to the single and same object
        // hence the values of the object are modified 
    } 

    void modify(Dimension dim)
    {
        dim.height = dim.height + 1;
    }   


}
```

The output is

```
Before passing the reference d.height = 10
After passing the reference d.height = 11
```

Comment: The Java Language Specification has [a whole section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8) discussing exactly how this happens, and it's special treatment for the wrapper types.

Answer (score 2):

The java compiler automatically inserts `intValue` and `Integer.valueOf` calls to convert between `int` and `Integer`. For example, here's a code snippet from the question:

```
void show(Integer x){
  x *=100 ;
}
```

And here is what really happens:

```
void show(Integer x) {
  int unboxed = x.intValue();
  unboxed *= 100;
}
```

As you can see, the line `x *= 100` does not really change the `Integer` object you pass in, it only changes the `int` value extracted from that `Integer` object.

In a similar way, the code `wi == pi` from the question actually means `wi.intValue() == pi`, which explains your observation.

Answer (score 0):

Java uses the "call by value" concept as described in detail [here](http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm)
So in your case x *=100 ; in method show only updates the local variable

Answer (score 0):

Compiler unboxes `wi` to primitive data type.So now, it is a primitive data type,since everything in Java is pass by value, changes in the formal arguments will not affect actual arguements.

```
mn.show(wi);
```